# How to detect programmatically that call is on hold in iOS?

Tags: ios, phone-call, core-telephony

Is it possible to get any event or notification regarding Telephony Call Hold in iOS.
`CTCallCenter` provides only following states :

```
CTCallStateDialing
CTCallStateIncoming 
CTCallStateConnected
CTCallStateDisconnected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use CallKit Framework to get the Call Hold event.

We need to conform to CXCallObserver Delegate

```
 [_callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

where _callObserver is the instance of my CXCallObserver class

```
- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.isOnHold == true) {
        NSLog(@"Call is on hold");
        }
}
```